# how to pass multiple inputs to a cosmosdb stored procedure

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

There are some great examples on [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs) for bulk inports and bulk deletes and I have been able to use python to get both of them to work.  for example
`dbclient.ExecuteStoredProcedure(parameterscolllink + '/sprocs/bulkImport', dumps(adddat), { 'partitionKey' : 0}))`

and then in my SPROC I deserialize the string into an array: `if (typeof items === "string") items = JSON.parse(items)`

But one of the examples from that MS page is an SPROC to swap fantasy football players, and the SPROC takes in 2 different variables:
`function tradePlayers(playerId1, playerId2)`

How would python execute an SPROC and pass 2 variables?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you? If you think it helps you,you could mark it for answer.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could pass multiple parameters as array to cosmos db stored procedure.

```
import azure.cosmos.cosmos_client as cosmos_client

endpoint = "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/";
primaryKey = "***";

client = cosmos_client.CosmosClient(url_connection=endpoint, auth={'masterKey': primaryKey})

sproc_link = "dbs/db/colls/jay/sprocs/test"

params = ["a","b"];

str = client.ExecuteStoredProcedure(sproc_link, params)
print(str);
```

Moreover,you could refer to this example:https://gist.github.com/sjwaight/3c5cf9503f588b190b5ff02bb79f07f0

---

***Update Answer:***

Sorry for the late. You could use `.net` code(Please see the case:[Unable to Execute procedure with multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821301/unable-to-execute-procedure-with-multiple-parameters)) to call that type like this:

```
var email = "xxxxx";
var password = "xxxx";
var response = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>(storedProcedurelink, new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey) },email,password);
```

I check the construct function of the `ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync`,it accepts Dynamic array.

[image]

As for python code,didn't find such invoke way.You still need to follow above sample code to pass the params into a list.

[image]

Comment: yes what you described is what Im doing now with an array - I just have to JSON-it in the SPROC - im just curious as to the example MS provided with the SPROC that apparently can accept 2 different inputs, and am wondering how to call that type of SPROC from the client code (python, .net, etc)

Comment: @OpticalCarrier Hi,please see my update answer ,thank you.